# Visualforce save only changed objects

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension

I have a visualforce page with a custom save method in which I'm saving multiple objects. I want to save only those objects which got modified. Currently I'm doing an upsert on all objects when save happens. How do I detect the dirty objects before saving?

Comment: You'll get much better answers if you share the code you already have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How do we prevent un-necessary updates on a record?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133627/how-do-we-prevent-un-necessary-updates-on-a-record)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking for is something analogous to Postgresql's [suppress_redundant_updates_trigger()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-trigger.html).

Unfortunately, that doesn't exist in Salesforce. The only way to prevent updates on unmodified records is to control which objects you update in your apex code.